# Change a non-floating point number the largest step

Tags: code-golf

Declare a numeric variable that is **not** floating point and do an operation that changes the value with the largest amount of difference so the result of the variable is far from the original value.

Solutions will be scored based on the magnitude of the difference between initial value and the value after changed, and shortness of code.

**Edit:**
 I realize that this was a bit vague - sorry about that, it's my first try on code golf...

I want to also emphasize that the result must not cause overflow. So once the variable is declared with a specific type (which must not be floating point), the result would have to be valid within that type.

Comment: Is the problem the following: `Given an integer N, return an integer D such that max(|N-D|,|D-N|) is maximized`?

Comment: You do realise that there are languages which allow arbitrarily large integers?

Comment: @trinithis: Not "return an integer". You must change the value of an integer variable that results in max diference.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: No, I just realized it with the [Phyton answer by JiminP](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/change-a-non-floating-point-number-the-largest-step/3798#3798). I have not very broad experience with such languages, and in my narrow mind, a numeric type has bounds, so I'm feeling his answer is cheating, but...

Comment: Python and Java are not eligible for this contest since their integers are immutable.

Comment: @awe, for a type with a fixed size this is a boring question. Initialise variable to maximum; change it to minimum. For a type with an arbitrary size it's slightly more interesting, but not an objective challenge until you specify the scoring more precisely.

Comment: @Peter Taylor:  awe specifies on the the comments that "you must change the value of an integer variable that results in max diference".  I'm pretty sure he means that he wants the value *at the original memory location* changed.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, and why would that be a problem in Java?

Comment: @Peter Taylor:  Whoops.  I'd not looked at Java recently.  My memory of strings being immutable somehow got cast onto Java primitives.

Comment: It is not an objective winning criterion, if you have 2 goals to reach. Person A might have the shortest code, Person B the greatest difference, Person C might have something in between for both aspects. You could solve the problem by a combined measure: `Maximise (100-code-size)*difference`, or by ordering the winning criteria: `Shortest code wins. For two equal shortest codes, the bigger difference wins.` Prepare your questions on meta or in chat next time, to solve such problems and ambiguities before starting the quiz.

Comment: This is (yet another) busy beaver problem.  Boo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Java (<strike>55</strike> <strike>26</strike> 19 chars, Diff: 2^64-1 = 18446744073709551615)

Given a very unclear spec on what we're supposed to be doing, here's a best try :-)  Obviously I will easily be beat out by languages that have arbitrary precision integers like Python or APL/J.

```
long o=Long.MIN_VALUE;o+=Long.MAX_VALUE+Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

Demo: http://www.ideone.com/7HyCW

**EDIT**: Shorter version, making use of Long underflow to wrap around from `MIN_VALUE` to `MAX_VALUE` (26 chars):

```
long o=Long.MIN_VALUE;o--;
```

Demo: http://www.ideone.com/Qfao7

**EDIT 2:** Shortest yet taking into account `@ratchet freak`'s suggestions:

```
long o=1L<<63;o=~o;
```

Demo: http://www.ideone.com/2M9oa

Comment: wouldn't `o=~o;` also work without overflow (and isn't `1<<63` or `-1>>>1` a shorter initialization)

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Updated with your suggestion.  Note have to use `1L<<63` otherwise it overflows at 2^32 because `1` is integer by default.

Answer (score 2):

### D (15 chars 2^64-1 difference)

```
ulong o=0;o=~o;
```

uses unsigned long and logical NOT to get max value

note that using `ucent` would get me to 2^128-1 difference (if it were to be implemented at least)

Comment: Just curious - what is `ucent`?

Comment: @awe a 128 bit unsigned integer but it's not yet part of the language (it's planned for when processors go 128 bit)

Comment: You will have one less char if you do `o--` instead of `o=~o`. It will both result in the inverted value, because `o--` will "wrap around" and use the max value of ulong (at least in C# where I tested it).

Comment: I haven't found the wrapping rules of unsigned types in D (which I think would undefined like in C)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell - 8 characters (Infinite difference)

`f=f.(+1)`

Use `f` on `Integer`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you defined a function; you didn't "do an operation."

Comment: Heh, well this problem cannot be done in Haskell otherwise. Yes, there are MVars and such, but that doesn't exactly cut it either.

Comment: The closest I can think of would be an action, but my main point is: from within Haskell, it's not possible to even verify that yours yields a number greater than the one it was given.

Answer (score 1):

### C with SSE2 (79 chars, Difference: 2^128-1 = 3.4e38)

```c
#include<emmintrin.h>
main(){__m128i v=_mm_set1_epi8(-1);v=_mm_xor_si128(v,v);}
```

This initially sets the 128 bit unsigned int `v` to its maximum value, and then changes this value to 0 by XORing `v` with itself.

Answer (score 1):

#### Golfscript

```
2{.?}9*
```

7 chars, unimaginably large difference. (The loop executes 9 times. The first time maps 2 -> 2^2 = 4. The second time maps 4 -> 4^4 = 256. The third time maps 256 -> 256^256 ~= 3.23 * 10^616. The fourth time overflows memory, but not the datatype...)

Comment: The requrements was to first declare a numeric variable (not float), then do the operation(s) on that variable.

Comment: @awe, in GolfScript a variable is just a value on the stack. If you want to write something which isn't GolfScript in GolfScript I suppose you could do `2:a;{a.?:a;}9*`

Comment: ... which would be 14 chars?

Comment: @userunknown, yes, like that. The problem is that the challenge isn't well enough specified for me to know how many of those characters are necessary; this was more a protest answer than anything.

Answer (score 1):

## J - 16 characters

```
a=.<.<:(a=.2)^31
```

The value of a changes from 2 to 2147483647. The calculation makes the value become float, but the final result is integer.

There are also extended integers, but I don't know if they would be acceptable.

```
a=.(a=.0)+!100000x
```

Yes, that really spells out mathematically as !100000. J can crunch it (in a few minutes), brute force.

Answer (score 0):

### Python (13 chars, Difference: 9^(9^9) (369,693,100 *digits*!))

```
a=0;a=9**9**9
```

I believe that the result of this operation is not a float, isn't it?

If that's problem because it doesn't yield the result...

### Mathematica (11 chars, Difference: only 15,151,335 digits)

[image: 8^8^8]

If it's still a problem because this value is not the maximum *possible*, then,
`a=2^1073741696;a*=-1` (20 chars) will do the work.

Comment: What type is `a` declared as? (implicit declaration?) Is this not causing overflow on the type of a?

Comment: @awe Python has arbitrary-precision integer. For example, `4**4**4` returns `13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084096L`. (PS: It is `4**(4**4)`; `(4**4)**4` returns only `4294967296L`.)

Comment: I added the calculation of Mathematica. If this is a problem because the difference isn't the maximum *possible*, then I'll go with `a=2^1073741696;a*=-1`

Comment: arbitrary-precision integer: I feel cheated...

Answer (score 0):

#### bc 15chars:

On my system I can go until 8^8^8 without error, but 6^6^6 would already be too long to report it here, so take 5^5^5 as an example; 7^7^7 is in the range of one minute on a single core 2Ghz machine. With 8 you should have some time left.

```
echo "k=8^8^8;k*=-1;k" | bc
```

printable result for one page:

```
echo "k=5^5^5;k*=-1;k" | bc
```

-1911012597945477520356404559703964599198081048990094337139512789246\
    52053024261580301205938651973985026558644015579446223535921278867380\
    69722884101469159866020879618967571957018392816603380476112259755336\
    26101001482651123413147768252411493094447176965282756285196737514395\
    35754247909321920664188301178716912255242107005070906467438287085144\
    99502565861944615431835113798491336917799281274338404315492368555267\
    83596374102105331546031353725325748636909159778690328266459182983815\
    23028693657287369142264813129174376213632573032164528297948686257624\
    53622180176732249405676428193600787207138370723553054463561539464011\
    85348493792719514594505508232749221605848912910945189959948686199543\
    14766693801303717616359259447974616422005088507946980448713320513316\
    07391342305401988725700383298012460501970134673971759090273894939238\
    17315786996845899794781068042822436093783946335265422815704302832442\
    38551508231649096728571217170812323279048181726832751011274678231741\
    09858886837085220007117334922539133223007561471804290075276777933523\
    06200618286012455254243061006894805446584704820650982664319360960388\
    73625851074707434063628697657670269925864995355797631817390255089133\
    12232947439303439561613283340728316634982581452268620043077990846881\
    03804187368324800903873596212919633602583120781673673742533322879296\
    90720549059562140688882599124458184237959786347648431567376092362509\
    03715117989414242622702200662864868678687101829808728025606931019492\
    80830825044198424796792058908817112327192301455582916746795197430548\
    02640464685400273399386079859446596150175258696581144756851004156868\
    77309037124825353438392853975987494584970500382250124892840018265900\
    56251286187629938044407340142347062055785305325034918189589707199305\
    66218851296318750174353596028220103821161604854512103931331225633226\
    07664362366882968502088394961428304847391139916696226499485636852347\
    12873294796680884509405893951104650944137909502276545653133018670633\
    52132302846051943438139981056140065259530073179077271106578349417464\
    26847209561346473277485842382748996687550525043942182321913572230540\
    66715373374248543645663782045701654593218154053548393614250664498585\
    40330746646854189014813434771465031503795417577862281177658587694168\
    0908203125

Answer (score 0):

### BrainF***, 3 characters, theoretically unlimited difference

```
[+]
```

Some implementations of BF wrap. "True" BF allows for unlimited integers. This has a difference of whatever you want it to be, plus it's only 3 characters long :)